# How to delete an element from an array which has alphabetic values in python

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, arraylist

I have an Array which has values `['a','b','e','d','f','e']`

First Question: How to delete element `e` from this array?

Second Question: What if i want to copy all the elements between the two `e` elements?

Comment: You have lists here

Comment: 2nd question: find the indexes of the 2 *e*s (before removing them) and do a slicing.

Comment: Did you try to solve this? if yes, then please post what you have tried and the errors you get. If no, then you should try to solve it first.

Comment: @CristiFati What if the indexes arent defined? What if the file is continuosly updating?

Comment: @AmritSingh i am still figuring out the code to answer the second question

Comment: The indexes are "defined" (assuming the elements are in the list). If they aren't in the list, the 2nd question makes no sense.

Comment: @MakInsane Just a suggestion...don't directly jump to the code. First, try to think the logic for the solution of the problem. Once you get the solution, implement it.

Comment: @CristiFati indexes are defined correct but their occurence is not defined.

Comment: i have the got the first question , I am still figuring out the second one @AmritSingh

Comment: I suppose you're looking for a more sophisticated answer than `your_array.index("e")` (https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) to find the indexes :d.